# Website won't be responsive in wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation

I've made a theme for wordpress. it's really simple one. and i wanted to work with foundation by zurb as a css framework.

I've did all necesary html to make it responsive. it looks nice on desktop browsers. and even if i change the browser size the website update the look.

But in mobiles it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting the meta viewport tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

The meta viewport tag allows you to tell the mobile browser what size the virtual viewport should be. Without this, your website will be rendered into the mobile device's default virtual viewport, thus acting the way it is now.